# How Do I report a scammer requesting money as PayPal bill?

Tags: scams, paypal

Today I received a PayPal request for payment for over $41000 from a party I don't know with a gmail address that looks like it was created just for scamming. Obviously I cancelled it, but is there anything I can to do to report this request as abuse/scam? Presumably a PayPal account prepared to receive that much money is connected to real banking information that could be used to identify the scammer. I could not however find any workflow for reporting it.

Comment: @RobertLongson: That doesn't seem to be a match because it's not a fake message. It was an actual unsolicited and unauthorized invoice. I did not interact with the email but logged into PayPal, saw it there as a bill, and opened it and clicked cancel. It's still there in "canceled" state but has no UI elements to report it as fraudulent.

Comment: Close Voters - This doesn't seem like OP is asking for product recommendations. Just a way to report fraud. Also it has useful answer. I think this should be re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

Paypal has a [security centre](https://www.paypal.com/us/security/home) that discusses how to report

- [fraud and unusual account activity](https://www.paypal.com/us/security/report-fraud). This option suggests a number of actions to take such as placing a fraud alert with credit bureaus and contacting financial institutions. Some actions depend on whether this an issue with a PayPal account or a PayPal card. If it's an account problem you can [login to the resolution centre](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fdisputes%2F).
- [suspicious emails or text messages](https://www.paypal.com/us/security/report-suspicious-messages). Here you would

  > Forward suspicious email to spoof@paypal.com

Follow the instructions to report your concerns to them and any other parties.

Answer (score 0):

Forward suspicious email to spoof@paypal.com
When you aren't sure if a message that appears to be from PayPal is really from them, don't click on any links, call any listed phone numbers, or download attachments. Forward the entire email to spoof@paypal.com and delete it from your inbox.